# Why should my training set also be skewed in terms of number of class distribution just because my test set is skewed

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, deep-learning, text-classification

My question is why should my training set also be skewed (number of instances of positive class much fewer compared to negative class) when my test set is also skewed. I read that it is important to maintain the distribution between the classes the same in both training and test set to get the most realistic performance. For example, if my test set has 90%-10% distribution of class instances, should my training set also have the same proportions?

I am finding it difficult to understand why is it important to maintain the proportions of class instances in the training set as present in the test set.

The reason why I find it difficult to understand is don't we want a classifier to just learn the patterns in both the classes? So, should it matter to maintain skewness in the training set just because the test set is skewed?

Any thoughts will be helpful

Comment: You're giving good reasons in the first paragraph but not elaborating why you find *them* difficult to believe. Do that, so people don't answer what you already know.

Comment: The datasets are skewed relative to *what*? If it's relative to the true distribution, then you probably have a GIGO situation. If not, then you just need to ensure the train data is not skewed relative to the test data (=> also the real data).

Comment: @AmiTavory Can you please elaborate on what is the GIGO situation?  Did you mean garbage in garbage out situation? I edited the question a bit to explain what is skewness here. It is basically the difference in proportions of class instances in the training set.

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar Yes, I meant GIGO the way you meant. Anyway, following the clarification of your question, I tried to answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you're asking about the rationale for using [Stratified Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling#Advantages) (e.g., as used in [Scikit's `StratifiedKFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html).

Once you've divided your data into train and test sets, you have *three* datasets to consider:

1. the "real world" set, on which your classifier will really run
2. the train set, on which you'll learn patterns
3. the test set, which you'll use to evaluate the performance of the classifier

(So the uses of 2. + 3. are really just for estimating how things will run on 1, including possibly tuning parameters.)

Suppose your data has some class represented far from uniform - say it appears only 5% of the times it would appear if classes would be generated uniformly. Moreover, you believe that this is not a GIGO case - in the real world, the probability of this class would be about 5%.

When you divide into 2. + 3., you run the chance that things will be skewed relative to 1.:

- It's very possible that the class won't appear 5% of the times (in the train or test set), but rather more or less.
- It's very possible that some of the feature instances of the class will be skewed in the train or test set, relative to 1.

In these cases, when you make decisions based on the 2. + 3. combination, it's probable that it won't indicate well the effect on 1., which is what you're really after.

Incidentally, I don't think the emphasis is on skewing the train to fit the test, but rather on making the train and test *each* fit the entire sampled data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I understand correctly, what you summarize is that it doesn't matter if the training set has equal proportions for the two classes or not. What is more important is that it learns patterns of both the classes, right? Thanks for explaining the justification behind the StratifiedKFold.

Comment: ... and that should mean that it is OK to have a balanced training set and later to test it on an imbalanced test set. Is that right?

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar I agree with your former point, but not the latter. Ideally, each set should be as representative of possible of the real world set (stratified sampling just tries to make this the case when you first sample a dataset, then break it into train + test). Anything else will likely: 1. cause the classifier to learn patterns incorrectly, 2. give the wrong feedback of the projected classifier performance, or 3. both.